# Cordova WebWorks API

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

I have a Phonegap-based web application, but would like to use parts of the WebWorks API (blackberry.payment) inside of it.

How could I go about doing so?

Note, I would also need it to work for BBOS 6.0+ and Playbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use cordova versions before 2.8 then all blackberry OS implementations (BBOS, tablet and BB10) are based on webworks. This means that all of the webworks APIs will be present (on BB10 you will need to include the webworks.js file). You should simply be able to use them so long as `<feature id="blackberry.payment" />` is present in your config.xml